# Read complex tab separated file(multiple column lines and line breaks) into the objects

Tags: vb.net

Ik have a tab separated data file. Each object is separated from each other with 2 line breaks and each object's first and third row is the column names.

**My Tab Separated File**

```
ID         [TAB] NAME     
001        [TAB] Croline            
DATE       [TAB] DOC
30/06/2010 [TAB] 101435

2 x EMPTY LINE                      

ID         [TAB] NAME     
002        [TAB] Grek            
DATE       [TAB] DOC   
30/06/2010 [TAB] 101437

2 x EMPTY LINE

...........
...........
```

**My Object Class**

```
Public Class MyObject
    Public Property Id As String
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Date As String
    Public Property Doc As String
End Class
```

How can I read this file into the MyObjects?

Comment: Each object can contain multiple date/doc pairs?  If so, your class needs to include a list of those, does it not?

Comment: @Steven Doggart so sorry, I've corrected my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to help you to understand how to do this without knowing, more specifically, what part of this task you are having trouble with, but perhaps a simple working example with help you get started.

If you define the your data class like this:

```
Public Class MyObject
    Public Property Id As String
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property [Date] As String  ' Note that "Date" must be surrounded with brackets since it is a keyword in VB
    Public Property Doc As String
End Class
```

Then you can load it like this:

```
' Create a list to hold the loaded objects
Dim objects As New List(Of MyObject)()

' Read all of the lines from the file into an array of strings
Dim lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines("test.txt")

' Loop through the array of lines from the file.  Step by 7 each 
' time so that the current value of "i", at each iteration, will 
' be the index of the first line of each object
For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Length Step 7
    If lines.Length >= i + 3 Then

        ' Create a new object to store the data for the current item in the file
        Dim o As New MyObject()

        ' Get the values from the second line
        Dim fields() As String = lines(i + 1).Split(ControlChars.Tab)
        o.Id = fields(0)
        o.Name = fields(1)

        ' Get the values from the fourth line
        fields = lines(i + 3).Split(ControlChars.Tab)
        o.Date = fields(0)
        o.Doc = fields(1)

        ' Add this item to the list
        objects.Add(o)
    End If
Next
```

The code to load it is very basic.  It does no extra validation to ensure that the data in the file is correctly formatted, but, given a valid file, it will work to load the data into a list of objects.

Comment: Slurping the whole file?  Are we intentionally teaching bad practice now?

Comment: @RoadieRich, I know what you mean, but it's not necessarily bad practice.  It all depends on the situation.  In any case, I was just trying to keep the example as simple as possible.  I'm assuming that, if the desire is to load all of the objects into a list in memory at once, then the list of objects in the file is a manageable size.  If it is bad to "slurp" the whole file at once, it would also likely be bad to store them all in memory at once too. :)

Comment: It's one of those things I consider a "start as you mean to go on" point. Set someone on the right path to begin with, and they'll stay on it until they learn when they can leave it.  Set someone on a less-than-ideal path, they'll likely stay on it until their first "business-critical" project runs out of memory.

Answer (score 1):

The solution will be something like (pseudocode):

```
Create an empty list of MyObjects
Open file for reading
While there are lines left to read:
    create a MyObject instance i
    read a line and ignore it.
    read a line into s1
    split s1 at tab character into a and b
    set i.Id to a1
    set i.Name to b1
    read a line and ignore it
    read a line into s2
    split s2 at tab character into a and b
    set i.Date to a2
    set i.Doc to b2
    add i to your list

    read a line and ignore it.
    read a line and ignore it.
```

Translating this into vb.net is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than writing specific code for that data, I'd first convert it to simple CSV. It might make sense if this is just a one-shot thing.

1) Load the file in Notepad++

2) Replace `\t` by `;` (using Extended Search Mode), giving you this kind of data :

```
ID;NAME
001;Croline
DATE;DOC
30/06/2010;101435


ID;NAME
002;Grek
DATE;DOC
30/06/2010;101437
```

3) Remove all `DATE;DOC` lines by searching for `DATE;DOC\n` and replacing with `;` (you might need to do *Edit > EOL Conversions > UNIX Format* for that to work)

4) Do the same to replace all `ID;NAME` lines by a placeholder symbol that is guaranteed not to be used in the data, maybe `£`. Your data should look like this :

```
£001;Croline
;30/06/2010;101435


£002;Grek
;30/06/2010;101437
```

5) Do *Edit > Blank Operations > Remove Unnecessary Blank and EOL*, which should put all your data on a single line.

6) Search & Replace your placeholder symbol `£` by `\n`

7) Remove extra blank line at the top. Voilà, you have a CSV file.

Comment: And if it isn't a one-shot thing... then what?

Comment: Well then you _make_ it a one-shot thing by telling whoever provides this data that they need to ditch their cutesy human-readable custom format and start using industry standards like CSV, JSON or XML, because they're not helping anyone, not even themselves.

Comment: And that's when you discover that the data comes from a program written in the 70s, running on hardware dating from before that, for which no-one has seen the source for thirty years.  *Then* what?

Comment: The rest of this discussion is left as an exercise to the reader.